# grouping more than once in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am new to mongo db,

I have a following code in mysql:

```
SELECT sum(Sentiment)/count(*), sum(Intensity)/count(*), count(*) FROM omid.tweet
```

and I need to convert it to mongodb:

but I am really confused with group bying more than one column for example I have :

```
// Now the $group operation
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$?????");
    groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$intensity"));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
```

but as you can see I do not know to group by on what and also how to get average for sentiment as well. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to group by more than once for what you are trying to achieve. You can use the [`$avg`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) and [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation operators of the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: null,
           avgSentiment: { $avg: "$sentiment" },
           avgIntensity: { $avg: "$intensity" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

**Untested** Java equivalent:

```java
// $group in Java
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", null);
groupFields.put("avgSentiment", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$sentiment"));
groupFields.put("avgIntensity", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$intensity"));
groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

// Run aggregation
List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(group);
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Thank you but this is the result: { "_id" :  null  , "averageSentiment" : 0.0 , "averageIntensity" : 0.0 , "count" : 222097} for some reason the average returns as null

Comment: @HamedMinaee, do you have null values for `intensity` and `sentiment` fields in your collection?  Or maybe the fields don't exist in some of the documents? If that's the case you may want to filter such documents out, before grouping.

Comment: @HamedMinaee, actually even with null/missing values in documents, it works just fine.. I just tested.. Maybe you can edit your question and post a sample document from your collection?

Comment: Hello again there is a problem that I am fighting with for 3 days can you please take a look,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015849/group-by-date-in-mogodb-query-without-considering-time