# group by date in mogodb query without considering time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

I have the following code:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Date");
    groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
    stages.add(groupBy);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    project.put("count", 1);
    project.put("Date", "$_id");
    stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", project));

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("Date", 1));
    stages.add(sort);
```

to group by Date and show the count which works fine but the problem is my date is in the following format:

"Date" : ISODate("2014-11-19T04:11:22.000Z")

and as you can see it has time as well but I want to group by date without considering time so I want to consider my date like this:
  2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z  but I do not know how to do that ...is there any mongodb function like date in mysql to do that?

Can anyone help?

Update:

I think this might be helpful but still do not know how to do it:
[link that might help](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)

Comment: I describe a detailed way to do exactly this here: http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework  but in 3.0.0 you can use $dateToString if you don't mind having a string be your _id/Date.

Answer (score 3):

The solution depends on whether you need to have the result "Date" as ISODate() type or if it's okay to get it back as a string.

If you are okay with string, new version of MongoDB (3.0) introduced [$dateToString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString) projection operator.

If it has to be ISODate() you can use the trick I describe in details in this blog post:  http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework

Comment: Thanks  a lot  , I think $dateToString works for me but I do not know how to apply $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } to grouping by line in java : DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Date"); Do you have any idea?

Comment: @HamedMinaee, before the `$group` stage, just add a `$project` stage and extract the date alone using `$dateToString`.  In the `$group` stage, you can use the extracted date for grouping by.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan thank u :) . My problem is I can not put format and date all together in projection I have this but not working :DBObject project1 = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString", "format: \"%Y-%m-%d\", date: \"$date");
  DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", project1);
  groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
  DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

Comment: do you mean "can not put .." as in "I'm trying and can't make it work"?  The issue is how you are constructing the object - you might try writing it in  json and then converting it. here's an example: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/

Comment: @AnandJayabalan I mean I can not figure out how to do the following :DBObject project1 = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString", "format: \"%Y-%m-%d\", date: \"$date"); even I tried it this way but I got error: DBObject format = new BasicDBObject("format", "%Y-%m-%d"); 
format.put("date", "$Date"); 
DBObject formattedDate = new BasicDBObject("$dateToString", format); 
project.put("yearMonthDay", formattedDate);